# Why doesn't my code knows there is something wrong PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, try-catch

This is my try statement

```
$query = "DELETEh FROM supers WHERE id = :id";
    try {
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
      $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
      $stmt->execute();
      $_SESSION['notification'] = "Hero was deleted sucessfully";
    }
```

and this is the rest of the code

```
 catch(PDOException $e) {
$_SESSION['notification'] = "There was an error deleting hero: " . $e->getMessage();


 }
  header("Location: notification.php");
  exit;
```

when this runs, it tells me that the hero was deleted successfully, even though it did not because there is an extra "h" after DELETE. Could anyone explain why is this not getting into the catch block please?

Comment: Are you sure you enabled `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you didn't do

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

when you opened the PDO connection. The default is `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT`. `$conn->prepare()` will return `FALSE` and you need to get the reason from `$conn->errorCode()` or `$conn->errorInfo()`.